# Breakpoints and debugging statements open "read-only inlined content"

Tags: debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

## Context:

I am working on a React.js app that uses Webpack, and I'm using VS Code as my editor.

The Webpack config is specifying `inline-source-map` as its `devtool` option. but I am using hot reloading, too. So, source maps actually come into the browser via this `webpack://` protocol.

I am using the following `launch.json` config:

```
{
    "name": "Launch in Chrome",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url" : "https://myapp.local/", // This is not the real app URL
    "trace" : true,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build",
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///*" : "${webRoot}/*"
    },
    "preLaunchTask" : "development",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
    "smartStep": true,
    "skipFiles": [
        "node_modules/**",
        "extensions:"
    ]
}
```

and I'm using [this `tasks.json`](https://github.com/skolmer/react-hot-boilerplate-vscode/blob/master/.vscode/tasks.json).

---

## Problem

So this mostly works well, except when I put a breakpoint somewhere, it opens the tab in a new tab marked as **read-only inlined content from source map**:

[image: read-only inlined content from source map]

**I just want to be able to debug and work on my files directly!**

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

This is because VC can't find the sources on the file system, so it resorts to using the copy it got from the web server.

This is typical in projects that span both server and client side code, and as a result, the web (HTML/JS/CSS) root is nested inside the workspace root. It can be easily fixed:

1. in VC, open the root folder of your project. go to "File -> Save workspace as" and save the workspace. Going forward always use the workspace (rather than folder) to enter your project.
2. In launch.json, set the webRoot value to reflect the relative path of the webRoot (typically folder with index.html). If your webRoot is under "UI", then it should look like this:

   ```
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/UI"
   ```

Comment: I have a docker Next.js project...when I try to add "webRoot" VC tells me that "Propety Webroot is not allowed."  Instead I have specified "localRoot" and "remoteRoot".  I am using a saved workspace to the root of my project. I can only get the debugger to work if I use the `debugger` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with this launch.json config. Hopefully it helps you.

```
{
  "name": "Launch localhost",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "attach",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "port": 9222,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:///./src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/*" },
  "sourceMaps": true,
}
```

Comment: This answer could be enhanced by explaining the reasoning behind your changes to the config to make it work successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue remote debugging Python, thanks the two above answers I was able to solve it.

1. as [SimbalCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912769/5898327) suggested I saved the workspace. I suppose this is needed to set your workspace folder path.

2. I then modified my `launch.json` as such:

```
{
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/Scripts/MyScripts/"
                }
            ],            
        }
```

Now the pathMappings are pointing to the correct file and upon debugger entry it is opening the correct file.