# Debugging with VS Code + Mocha and breakpoint stops at 'read-only inlined content from source map' file

Tags: node.js, debugging, mocha.js

I know, I know.

VS Code version: 1.25.1
Mocha: 4.0.1

Running mocha via launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "mocha",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "args": ["--no-timeouts", "--colors"], //you can specify paths to specific tests here
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": null,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "testing"
    },
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/dist"
    ],
  }
```

and set breakpoint in a file will open another tabbed window of same file with new title *"read-only inlined content from source map"* and breakpoint may be misaligned.  In addition, you try to edit file and you realize you can't.

After flailing at different solutions, dang if setting the sourceMap to **false** worked for me:

```
 "sourceMaps": false,
```

Note: the "outFiles" did nothing, it is an artifact of trying different solutions, including build a map to /dist.

I'm not sure what changed in my configuration/setup.  I just upgraded to vscode 1.25, but I don't really know.

This answer is the **opposite** of [Breakpoints and debugging statements open "read-only inlined content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880608/breakpoints-and-debugging-statements-open-read-only-inlined-content)

Good luck!

Comment: Did you mean to post this in reply to another question?

Answer (score 2):

*Reposting answer from above:*

In launch.json:set sourceMaps to false:

**"sourceMaps": false,**

This answer is the **opposite** of [Breakpoints and debugging statements open "read-only inlined content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880608/breakpoints-and-debugging-statements-open-read-only-inlined-content)