# How do I enable editable debugging of files within VS Code w/ Chrome Debugging?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

Environment:

- OS: macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 (20G95)
- Chrome: Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- VSCode: Version: 1.60.1
  Commit: 83bd43bc519d15e50c4272c6cf5c1479df196a4d
  Date: 2021-09-10T17:09:14.403Z (5 days ago)
  Electron: 13.1.8
  Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
  Node.js: 14.16.0
  V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
  OS: Darwin x64 20.6.0

---

### My action:

1. {**VSCode**} Open the workspace containing my project directory.
2. {**VSCode**} Add the following block to 'launch.json' in the "configurations" array:

```
{
   "type": "pwa-chrome",
   "request": "attach",
   "name": "Attach Chrome Debugging to Browser for VSCode",
   "port": 9222,
   "url": "http://localhost:8888/",
   "urlFilter": "http://localhost:8888/*",
   "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

3. {**VSCode**} Save 'launch.json'
4. {**Chrome**} Close all running instances of Chrome
5. {**Terminal**} Navigate to root (`/`)
6. {**Terminal**} Run the command: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile`

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**Chrome**} Application opens with a popup (not as expected):
   [image: Screenshot of popup with text reading: "Google Chrome cannot read and write to its data directory: remote-debug-profile]

---

### My action:

1. {**Chrome**} Click "Ok" button.

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**Chrome**} A window opens prompting "Who's using Chrome?" with an option to select my desired user profile as expected.

---

### My action:

1. {**Chrome**} Click on my desired user profile.

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**Chrome**} A window opens with my desired user profile logged in as expected.

---

### My action:

1. {**VSCode**} Add a breakpoint to my code via a `debugger;` statement in my HTML file.
2. {**VSCode**} Click "Run" button with my debugging profile selected.
3. {**Chrome**} Conduct behavior to trigger breakpoint in my code.

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**VSCode**} The breakpoint is triggered **HOWEVER:** it is triggered in a "read-only" version of my file, opened in a new tab separate from my actual file.

---

## My Desired Outcome

**Using "attach"** I want to be able to have the breakpoint activate inside of the actual file in VSCode, not a "Read-Only" version.

---

I've spent about two hours researching this issue and as far as I can tell it has to do with:

- The location I'm running the terminal command from. I tried:

  - Running it from the project directory, however it dumped a ton of code into my project directory **AND** failed to open an instance of Chrome where I could select my desired user profile - instead opening up a user profile agnostic Chrome window.
- The `--user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile` line in the terminal command.
- My configuration in Launch.JSON. I've tried combinations of:

  - `"type": "chrome"`
  - `"webRoot": "*/thedirectpathtomyprojectdirectory*"`
  - `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"`
  - `"userDataDir": "/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1"`
  - `"userDataDir": "/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome"`
  - `"sourceMapPathOverrides": {"webpack://?:*/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"}`
  - `"sourceMaps": true`

### *I'm at a total loss!*

Comment: Did you try this? [Breakpoints and debugging statements open "read-only inlined content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880608/breakpoints-and-debugging-statements-open-read-only-inlined-content)

Comment: @OfirD Yes I did, and no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `--user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile`

See here - https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md

You need to supply an actual directory path.

1. Copy your current User Data folder to your custom dir
2. Point chrome shortcut to the custom dir using the --user-data-dir parameter

Comment: Do you mind adding more granularity? My understanding is that I either need to add the direct path to my User Data folder to the terminal command, OR that I must copy that User Data folder into the 'custom dir' of my project in vscode, and then point to that path from the terminal command. The first option is not working.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1130368/chrome-user-data-dir-not-working-properly - Try the solutions in this link.